# Can i create an interface object and reach to the function of the java file that implements the interface without overriding it?

Tags: java, interface

//Interface class

```
public interface Square {

    public void printHeight();
    public void printWidth();
}
```

//java class that implements the interface class

```
public class Square1 implements Square{

    public void printHeight(){
        System.out.println("height");
    }

    public void printWidth(){
         System.out.println("width");
    }
}
```

//Action class that will create object an interface without overriding the methods
    public class test extends *someabstractclass*{

```
    private Square perfectSquare;


    @Override
    public void print(){
       perfectSquare.printHeight();
    }     
}
```

When running this perfectSquare.printHeight() it able to show in console

```
    height
```

How does it work?

Comment: As it currently stands this code will not even compile. 1. printHeight and printSquare have a wrong return type. 2. `public void printWidth{` is not valid java code, you are missing `()`

Comment: Thank you @OHGODSPIDERS . i had edited the silly error i had made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This declaration defines a variable of an interface type (`Square`):

```
private Square perfectSquare;
```

That variable can contain a reference to an object of a class (such as your `Square1` class) that implements the `Square` interface.

Therefore you can call methods of the `Square` interface on that variable (such as `perfectSquare.printHeight()`).

Of course, this assumes you initialize the variable before using it. Otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException` in runtime.

Given the "height" output which you claim you got, you probably assigned to the `perfectSquare` variable an object of the `Square1` class (in some code you didn't include in the question).